# Как при запросе к сайту отловить все 'подзапросы'?

Tags: веб-программирование, .net

Обращаюсь к яндексу через `HttpWebRequest`, в ответном `HttpWebResponse` получаю одну куку. Но! Заюзал плагин `LiveHTTPHeaders` для фаерфокса - после основного запроса к `yandex.ru/yandexsearch` происходят еще несколько подзапросов к яндексовским ресурсам типа `yandex.st` и `yabs.yandex.ru`, часть из которых тоже возвращает куки, но в `HttpWebResponse` их нету. Как отловить эти подзапросы?

Comment: так вы их этим плагином уже отловили, этого мало?
`HttpWebRequest` сам не будет запрашивать ничего, кроме указанного адреса - это не браузер. в браузере эти запросы происходят либо из-за загрузки внешних ресурсов страницы (картинки, скрипты, стили), либо их делают сами скрипты `ajax`-ом

Comment: Вам придётся сделать то же, что делает браузер: распарсить полученный HTML и загрузить рекурсивно все вложенные документы, выполнить javascript, захостить Flash и всё такое. Вам оно нужно?